# Understanding everything about SSH keys

Tags: linux, ssh, webserver, sftp, linux-server

consider me as noob, but I've 0 idea about ssh keys, I know ssh is very secure, one thing I know, that you don't need to remember password when you like to access your remote server, now i've 3 remote linux servers and my `.ssh` folder has files like this

- server_1.key
- server_1.pem
- id_rsa
- id_rsa.pem
- id_rsa.pub
- key
- known_hosts
- server_2.key
- server_2.pem
- server_3.key
- server_3.pem

now I've no idea what these files and what is their purpose, one thing i know, i have to add `key` file to my filezilla so if can use sftp, secondly when i want to access server_1, i've to do `ssh .ssh/server_1.key user@server.com` which let's me access the server, now problem occurred when I created `server_2`, I can access via `ssh` but I'm unable to connect via filezilla to transfer files.

I know if you are system admin / pro in this field this is a very lame question, but being noob I would love if anyone could explain in detail, so i can start managing them correctly.

**Things I'm looking in answer**

- what key does what
- what if I have to format / reinstall new os in my system, which files to save(backup)
- how is it i'm able to ssh server_2 but unable to access it via filezilla
- I've have a passphrase in `key` file, how can I change it
- What if I want to change `server_1.key` `server_1.pem` keys just like we change our password

Would love a details answer, please don't downvote this question, i've googled a lot, this will not only help me but will help future noobs in this field, thank you

posted on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36327791/understanding-everything-about-ssh-keys)

Comment: Please do **not** crosspost. See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068)

Answer (score 0):

> - What key does what

All the keys do authentication. Except `known_hosts`, which is just a list of known hosts and their public host keys.

> - what if I have to format / reinstall new os in my system, which files to save(backup)

All of them.

> - how is it I'm able to ssh server_2 but unable to access it via filezilla

Probably wrong configuration in FileZilla. You didn't show it to us, so we have no idea to verify what is wrong.

> - I've have a passphrase in `key` file, how can I change it

From manual page for `ssh-keygen`:

> The passphrase can be changed later by using the -p option."

```
 ssh-keygen -p [-P old_passphrase] [-N new_passphrase] [-f keyfile]
```

> - What if I want to change `server_1.key` `server_1.pem` keys just like we change our password

Generate public key from the new one:

```
 ssh-keygen -y [-f input_keyfile]
```

and replace the old public key in the server's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`